# Sandbox Multiple Files Together

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use a local installation of [tesseract.js][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js in a Chrome extension
and currently have a directory with tesseract.js, worker.js, and core.js. tesseract.js uses worker.js through a Web Worker and worker.js uses core.js through an ImportScript. Core.js has frequent usage of eval(), so I need to sandbox it. Is there a way to sandbox tesseract.js, worker.js and core.js together, just sandbox core.js while keeping it accessible to worker.js through ImportScript, or just sandbox tesseract.js while giving it access to worker.js and core.js?

Comment: Whynot? [Sandboxed pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) are html so you can include as many js files as you want.